# Dynamic SQL - Make the query run 15 minutes from its last exec time

Tags: dynamic-sql

I have a script looking for records in the past 15 minutes. This scripts run as job automation from another server. Script is below

```
SELECT om.OrderMarketRef, o.OrderRef, o.OrderID,s.SecurityName,s.SEDOL,a.AccountID,a.AccountName,c.CompanyID AS BranchCode, n.LogItemMessage + ISNULL ('  User comment: ' + n.UserComment, '')AS AuditMessage, u.UserName, n.LogItemTimeStamp AS AuditTimeStamp, o.TargetConsiderationTrade, o.TargetAmount, o.TargetQuantity, n.ChangeLogRef,o.CreationDate
             FROM Order_LogItem n WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Orders o WITH (NOLOCK) ON n.MasterOrderRef = o.MasterOrderRef         
INNER JOIN dbo.Account a WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.AccountRef = a.AccountRef 
INNER JOIN dbo.Company c WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.CompanyRef = c.CompanyRef
LEFT JOIN [User] u ON u.UserRef = n.UserRef
LEFT JOIN Orders_Market om WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.OrderMarketRef = om.OrderMarketRef    
INNER JOIN dbo.[Security] s WITH (NOLOCK) ON om.SecurityRef = s.SecurityRef
WHERE n.LogItemMessage LIKE '%Cannot insert duplicate key row in object%' AND  

--  -- Only consider orders created within 30 minutes of each other
o.CreationDate>= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())
```

However, if the server where the sql running from is having issues, then the script may delay. For instance, script runs at 11:30 looking at records from 11:15 to 11:30. Then the next script is scheduled to run as automation from 11:45 but then the job may delay and run at 12:00 meaning it will look for records from 11:45. So we are not checking records then from 11:30

What I want to do is to make the script more dynamic so when it runs, it look at past 15 minutes from the last time the script was executed. How would I get the script past execution time and use it in my WHERE clause to look for 15 minutes onwards from that time.

Thanks

Tried 15 minutes manually but want to make it more dynamic. Looked online to Microsoft resources.